# My ubuntu version is showing ubuntu 13.04 version

Tags: package-management

My ubuntu version is showing ubuntu 13.04 version,but inside of  sourcelist is showing like this below screen shot even i can't download many packages.
[image]

Comment: where is the screenshot?

Comment: @maythux it was in the text but with the [1]: in front of it ;-)

Comment: Did you upgrade Ubuntu? Did you do a fresh install using a live USB?

Comment: @Rinzwind Ok got it friend

Comment: @user244776 what is the output of the command `lsb_release -d`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have added a wrong repository.

Simply just open  the sources.list

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then remove the lines that includes the codename Quantal

Then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and now you are on the safe side :)